# gnuplot highlighting points when with lines

Tags: plot, gnuplot, highlight

I have 4 points I would like to plot using gnuplot, but with lines. The problem is, I can't find how to highlight these 4 points on the drawn line. I would like for the plot to be a line through the points, but that these points are also clearly marked. An [example](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/images/line-chart/line-chart.png) generated by excel. What I know is either drawing only points, or only a line with no highlighted points. Is a combination possible in gnuplot?

Comment: Use `plot ... with linespoints`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From gnuplot [docs](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node62.html), define styles as:

```
set style line 1 lc rgb '#0060ad' lt 1 lw 2 pt 5 ps 1.5   # blue
set style line 2 lc rgb '#dd181f' lt 1 lw 2 pt 7 ps 1.5   # red
...
```

and plot:

```
plot ... w lp ls 1    # Use line style 1
```

where:

```
lc - linecolor
lt - linetype
lw - linewidth
pt - pointtype
ps - pointsize
w  - with
lp - linespoints
ls - linestyle
```

or one line shorthand:

```
plot ... w lp lc rgb 'cyan' lw 2 pt 5
```

line style 1 will produce blue line with square points